# Ubuntu 20.04 File, list view, icon size too big

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, themes

Using Ubuntu 20.04.2, Gnome 3.36.8,
GTK Theme: [Cameo-Alu-Dark-Traditional](https://www.pling.com/p/1397841/)
Icon pack: [Flattery](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1332404/)

In the File application, the icons looks too big. As a result, there are fewer items displayed in the screen. Is there a way to have a more compact list view with smaller icon size?

[image]

Comment: You tried zooming out (Ctrl+Shift+-)? Does the issue happen also with the default Yaru theme? If no, then it is a problem with the theme you use.

Comment: @vanadium OMG thank you for teaching me that the Gnome File app is zoomable! The fix is straight forward, just Ctrl + Scroll wheel to set the zoom level and that's it. Regarding the key shortcut, somehow `Ctrl-Shift-+` works but not with `-` to zoom out. Can you make an answer (instead of comment) so I can mark as answer ?

Comment: It is Ctrl+- to zoom out and Ctrl+Shift++ to zoom in. Added this as an answer indeed, glad it helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icons can be sized by "zooming". Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>=/+</kbd> will zoom in. You can also zoom in or out from the button with the down pointing triangle (▼) or using the mouse scroll wheel while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.